# How to create loop in VBS?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a VBS script that connects to a FoxPro database.

```
Dim oCN : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
oCN.Open sCS
Dim oRS : Set oRS = oCN.Execute("SELECT SN_ANALSYS, SN_CRLIM, SN_CURRBAL FROM " & WScript.Arguments(0) & "_SNAME.DBF WHERE SN_ANALSYS != '' ORDER BY SN_ANALSYS ASC")
Do Until oRS.EOF
   WScript.Echo oRS.Fields(0).value, "50", oRS.Fields(1).Value
   WScript.Echo oRS.Fields(0).value, "51", oRS.Fields(2).Value
   oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oCN.Close
```

I run it via a BAT:

```
C:\query.vbs A > \\share\results.txt
```

The `A` is used in the query (`WScript.Arguments(0)`). However I want to be able to do this:

```
C:\query.vbs A,D > \\share\results.txt
```

So that it runs 2 queries using `A` and `D` but the results go to the same `results.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`WScript.Arguments.Unnamed` collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah2hawwc(v=vs.84).aspx).

```
Dim arg

For Each arg in WScript.Arguments.Unnamed
    ' use arg in the SQL query
Next
```

and call without a comma, so that cmd.exe recognizes them as separate arguments:

```
C:\query.vbs A D > \\share\results.txt
```